# Not all results included with parent-child query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to query ES (v. 2.2.0) and get child documents with their parents.

My Structure: `post` is a parent of `campaignPost`; `campaignPost` is a child of `post`.

And here is mapping for `campaignPost`:
http://pastebin.com/iAaAzdp3

Now in my index I've got 20 `posts` and 10 `campaignPosts` mapped to 10 of existing `posts`. The problem is that I'm expecting 10 records in the result but I've got only 4! Here is how I query ES:
http://pastebin.com/1vWwbMA2

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similiar problem with parent child relationship where my child type was parent of another type. Problem relied on routing parameter what was unsuitable for my granchildren. According to [ES documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/grandparents.html) my _routing parameter had to point on grandfather type. 
The parent parameter is used to link the children with its parent, but the routing parameter ensures that it is stored on the same shard as its parent and grandparent. The routing value needs to be provided for all single-document requests.

Try to set your **_routing** parameter properly and let me know if it helps.